# using powershell on Linux with Ansible

Tags: scripting, ansible, puppet, chef, powershell

In looking at powershell, the general assumption is that it's being used either for or on Windows machines in a homogeneous network.

Strictly within Linux, and only using "core" powershell, looking at [automation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/shell/powershell.html):

> You are reading an unmaintained version of the Ansible documentation.
>   Unmaintained Ansible versions can contain unfixed security
>   vulnerabilities (CVE). Please upgrade to a maintained version. See the
>   latest Ansible documentation.

How can I use powershell in Linux to admin Linux with Ansible?

Comment: Ansible v2.5 is unsupported.  Use the latest docs to get up to date information:  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/shell/powershell.html

Comment: any alternatives, as a suggestion?

Comment: Did you read the latest documentation I linked in my last comment?  It explains how to use the latest (i.e. v2.9) `powershell` plugin with Ansible.

Comment: pardon, @GracefulRestart.  I'm seeing that it says "windows powershell" so is that only on or for Windows systems?

Comment: According [to the releases page of the PowerShell source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases), it is available for most major operating systems.

Comment: Your above link is for Powershell Core. As explained on their [Readme](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), it is not windows powershell. The ansible module targets windows powershell only. I guess you could install and run powershell core script under linux via the shell using the pwsh command if I understand their documentation correctly...

Comment: ah, yeah, I was looking I suppose for a module which would target Linux, then.  Thanks @Zeitounator